# Why is the stereographic projection a map from $S^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, stereographic-projections, open-map

How can I understand that the *stereographic projection* $$X=\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos\phi,\hspace{0.5cm}Y=\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\sin\phi\tag{1}$$ is a map from the surface of a unit sphere to a plane? For (1) to be map from $S^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$, shouldn't $X,Y$ vary from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ for the allowed ranges of $\theta,\phi$?

Does it suffice to see that $X,Y$ are real? I think it's not because $\theta,\phi$ themselves were real. Then why is this a map from $S^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and **not** from $S^2\to \mathcal{M}$ where $\mathcal{M}$ is some other 2-dimensional manifold?

Comment: Treat it separabely. A prerequisite / simpler case study is the polar decomposition $\cases{x = r\cos(\phi)\\y=r\sin(\phi)}$. We have one more parameter and one more "dimension" (in some sense).

Comment: Two caveats: (1) note that a map from $S^2\mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ doesn't have to be a map _onto_ $\mathbb{R}^2$, any more than $f(x) = x^2$ isn't a function from $\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ just because it doesn't yield any negative values. (2) strictly speaking, the projection _isn't_ a map from $S^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}^2$ because it omits one point of $S^2$. It would be better to say that it's a map $S^2-\{p\}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^2$, where $\{p\}$ is the north pole of the sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any point in $\mathbf R^2\smallsetminus\{0\}$ has polar coordinates $(r\cos\phi, r\sin\phi), \; r>0$ . So all you have to prove is that any $r>0$ can be written as $\cot\Bigl(\dfrac\theta2\Bigr)$ for some $\theta$. This is obvious, just taking a look at the curve $y=\cot x$.

Comment: Now I realize that this is also clear from the way stereographic projections are defined. Thanks.